# Scrapy 1.0 - Log Configuration

Tags: python, debugging, web-crawler, scrapy

I need change the values about "Log_count/DEBUG" and "item_scraped_count".

I don't know do that, i need change something in some script or in scrapy configurations?

[image: This problem continues, my real problem is OUTPUT the program print many times the same answer(456), i need stop this and print once]

Comment: you can override the extensions that take care of those stats, but why would you want to change them manually? wouldn't it be better to create your own stats?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to [settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-settings):

```
LOG_ENABLED = True,
LOG_FILE = 'log_filename.log',
LOG_ENCODING = None
```

Comment: This problem continues, my real problem is OUTPUT the program print many times the same answer(456), i need stop this and put print once

Comment: @CaioFernandes  Check all page Scrapy's logging. Alsom check python logging